# Creating a modal that open next to the button that opens it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I know this may sound like a stupid question but I am really stumped been at it for a while without success.

I am looking for a way to create a modal or dropdown that opens next to the button that opens it. Much like the Google app launcher. I have tried with a select but the styling options are limited. I am not sure if it should be done with a select or a modal.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to post your attempt as a code snippet (`<>` button in the editor), so others can help you find a solution faster :)

Comment: That's the problem, I am not sure what to use. Dont know if it should be a dropdown or a modal.

Comment: Consider using a library, [here's one](https://testbed.nicon.nl/showFiddle/4y2crLe3) I created, or [tippy](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/) or use [css-only](https://dev.to/antinomaino/create-pure-simple-css-tooltips-42mh), or consider if just a `title`-attribute may be sufficient

Answer (score 1):

I will just give you an idea where to start. This will not be pretty.

Have a `button` and your modal `div` (or dropdown) in one same `div`.

```
<div>
    <button onclick="showModal()">Click this.</button>
    <div id="modal">This is modal.</div>
</div>
```

And make your modal `position: absolute;` in style and hide it until you click the button.

```
#modal {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

You should have a JS function for opening or showing the modal.

```
function showModal() {
    document.getElementById('modal').style.display = "block";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a class called modal-open-button to the button and then add this click event your your JS.

```
$(".modal-tooltip-button").click(function () {
    var modalID = $(this).attr("data-target");
    var topOffset = 100; 
    var thisLeft = $(this).offset().left;
    var thisTop = $(this).offset().top - topOffset;
    var thisWidth = $(this).width();
    var thisHeight = $(this).height();
    var idWidth = $(modalID).width();
    var idHeight = $(modalID).height();
    $(modalID + " .modal-content").css({ left: thisLeft - Number(idWidth / 2) + Number(thisWidth / 2), top: thisTop - Number(idHeight / 2) + Number(thisHeight) });
});
```